# Prescribing axes to the figure in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have created a 3x3 subplots by using the pandas df.line.plot:

```
ax=df.plot.line(subplots=True, grid=True,layout=(3, 3), sharex=True, legend=False,ylim=[-5,25])
```

It returns 3x3 matrix of Axes objects.
Now I want to create a joint legend for those subplots.

As the other post suggests I should use:

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
fig.legend(handles, labels, loc='upper center')
```

The problem is I can't use it because I have no figure created here. I only have axes. How can I make it work?

I edited the post, because I thought I could create a figure and prescribe the axes, but I guess it came from my confusion on subject.

Comment: do you mean `ax[0,0]`?

Comment: I want to add all subplots to the figure, maybe I am confused because when I create the plot with df.table.plot I do not create a figure, but just axes?

Comment: Yes, it returns a numpy array of axes.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

---

**First:** Either use double indices (for row and column) as shown in the comments and then use `ax[0,0]`, `ax[0,1]`, `ax[0,2]` ... `ax[2,0]`, `ax[2,1]`, `ax[2,2]`. For 3 rows and 3 columns, the indices will run from 0 up to 2 (so 0, 1, 2)

You can also use `ax[0][0]` and so on. Both formats are equivalent.

---

**Second:** If you don't want to use two indices, you can flatten the `ax` and then use a single index as

```
ax = ax.flatten()
```

This will convert `ax` from 2d object to a 1-d array of 9 subfigures. Then you can use `ax[0]`, `ax[1]`, `ax[2]`, ... `ax[8]` (9-1 because indexing starts from 0 in python)

Comment: Thanks, And then how should I add them to the figure?

Comment: @szczor1 : I do not understand what you mean by adding them to the figure. Which figure?

Comment: I edited my question, I am sorry for the confusion, which probably comes from my not-understanding the subject